# How to register a ServiceHelper for each IService in Autofac ContainerBuilder?

Tags: dependency-injection, .net-core, autofac

I'm creating a DI convenience nuget package that would add easy one-function registrations of components (in the spirit of `.AddEntityFramework()`-like methods) to go along with my main package.

Basically the users of library will register one or more `IService` (singleton) instances, and then call my method `RegisterServiceHelpers()`.

What I want method to do is register a helper for each `IService` the user has registered. Example method (not working)

```cs
public static void RegisterServiceHelpers(this ContainerBuilder self)
{
    foreach (var service in self.Build().Resolve<IEnumerable<IService>>())
        self.Register(c =>
            new ServiceHelper(service)).SingleInstance();
}
```

This is impossible because Autofac only allows calling `.Build()` once.

Also I attempted to exploit implicit list supports like this

```cs
self.Register(c => c.Resolve<IEnumerable<MessageBusFactory>>()
    .Select(factory =>
        new RabbitMqHealthCheckHandler(
            factory,
            c.Resolve<ILogger<RabbitMqHealthCheckHandler>>())))
        .SingleInstance()
    .As<IEnumerable<IHealthCheckHandler>>();
```

But this does not work, not to mention the wrong scope on `SingleInstance()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AttachToComponentRegistration` method of a module let you add dynamic registration.

```cs
class XModule : Module
{
    protected override void AttachToComponentRegistration(
        IComponentRegistry componentRegistry, IComponentRegistration registration)
    {
        base.AttachToComponentRegistration(componentRegistry, registration);

        if (registration.Services.OfType<IServiceWithType>()
            .Any(s => s.ServiceType == typeof(IService)))
        {
            IComponentRegistration r = RegistrationBuilder
                .ForType<ServiceHelper>()
                .WithParameter(
                    (pi, c) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(IService),
                    (pi, c) => c.ResolveComponent(
                        registration, Enumerable.Empty<Parameter>()))
                .SingleInstance()
                .CreateRegistration();

            componentRegistry.Register(r);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can register your module like `builder.RegisterModule<XModule>()`

Comment: Another option would be to use `IRegistrationSource` but we need more detail on what you want to do